# .htaccess Add an exception to 404 redirect to particular sub-directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, http-status-code-404

The sub-directory is /addon/ it stores all data for my sub-domains a.k.a addon domains.
In this sub-directory I also store my primary domains data, my primary domain is website.com

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/addon/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

Okay so that part is done, if I enter website.com/addon/mysecondwebsite-com I get a 404. 
If I enter mysecondwebsite.com I see the contents of website.com/addon/mysecondwebsite-com.

This is great, thats what I wanted.

*Now the tricky part, I already set up website.com to use website.com/addon/website-com. No need to tell me how to configure /addon/website-com for website.com. I need to disable 404 for website.com which is configured to use /addon/website-com/* but I also need to make sure if I enter website.com/addon/website-com that this directory is returned a 404.*

My rewrite conditions mention if I enter /addon/* on my primary domain (website.com) I will be returned a 404 error. This is great for my addon domains because they use /addon/ and not my primary domain. But how do I also block /addon/* but still use my primary domain?

- **website.com** = **404 / BAD** (website.com/addon/website-com)
- **mysecondwebsite.com** = **200 / Good** (website.com/addon/mysecondwebsite-com)
- **website.com/addon/mysecondwebsite-com** = **404 / Good**
- **website.com/addon/website-com** = **404 / Good**

---

Just so you get the full picture this is my .htaccess file for /public_html/

```
# Part one block direct access to /addon/ folder
RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/addon/(.*)$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]

# Part two using /addon/website-com/ as website.com directory
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/addon/website-com/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /addon/website-com/$1
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
        RewriteRule ^(/)?$ addon/website-com/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your 404 handler with this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+addon/ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^404\.shtml$)^.*$ - [L,R=404,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you! This works exactly as I wanted, except for the error pages for /addon/* they are not my typical error page. How can I force my custom 404 page to display when somebody goes to website.com/addon/* ... this is the 404 error I get; `The requested URL /addon/website-com was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: I didn't see any ErrorDocument line in your .htaccess. Probably you will need something like this: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml`

Comment: I need to be offline, it you have further questions, leave a comment and I will attend in few hours.

Comment: ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml works fine for everything other than /addon/* this has to be some kind of  block loop effect which is throwing off the error 500.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out.